# Prove that $\lim_{x\to a}e^x=e^a$

Tags: calculus, limits, epsilon-delta

> Prove by epsilon-delta limit definition that: $\lim_{x\to a}e^x=e^a$

My definition of exponential function is $e^x=\lim_{n\to \infty}(1+x/n)^n$. My teacher said that we need to use it but when I use the epsilon-delta definition I have that $$|\lim_{n\to \infty}(1+x/n)^n-\lim_{n\to \infty}(1+a/n)^n|<\epsilon$$ then I don't know how to proceed from here

Comment: What is the definition of $e^x$ you are using in your course?

Comment: what you learned so far? MVT?

Comment: The standard way of proving this, I believe, is to simply define $$\log x = \int_1^x \frac{1}{t}\, dt,$$ and then to define $\exp$ as the inverse function to $\log$. By the First Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, $\log$ is continuous, and then it from the theorem that the inverse of a continuous a function is continuous, we know that $\exp$ is continuous. Doing an epsilon-delta proof, however, will depend on the definition of $e^x$ you want to use.

Comment: My definition is $e^x=\lim_{n\to \infty}(1+x/n)^n$. My teacher said that we need to use it but when I use the epsilon-delta definition I have that $|\lim_{n\to \infty}(1+x/n)^n-\lim_{n\to \infty}(1+a/n)^n|<\epsilon$ then I don´t know how to proceed from here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$|e^x - e^a| = e^a|e^{x - a} - 1|$, then it is enough to show that $\lim_{x \to 0}e^x = 1$.

Use that $$a^n - b^n = (a - b)(a^{n - 1} + ba^{n - 2} + \dots + b^{n - 1})$$ to rewrite the limit as follows: $$\lim_{x \to 0}\big|\lim_{n\to \infty}(1 + xn^{-1})^n - 1\big| = \lim_{x \to 0}\big|\lim_{n \to \infty}(1 + xn^{-1} - 1)((1 + xn^{-1})^{n - 1} + \dots)\big|$$
Now, without loss of generality, assume that $x \le 1$. Noticing that in the second expression between parenthesis we have $n$ terms, all of which are smaller than $e$, we get: $$\lim_{x \to 0}\big|\lim_{n \to \infty}(1 + xn^{-1} - 1)((1 + xn^{-1})^{n - 1} + \dots)\big| \le \lim_{x \to 0}\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{x}{n}\cdot ne = \lim_{x \to 0}xe = 0$$

Comment: This assumes that $\lim_{n \to \infty}(1+x/n)^n = e^x$.

Comment: which is exactly the definition the OP claims to have in the comments under the question... what can I say, sometimes all you've got to do is downvote the question and have fun answering it anyway... :) I like yours btw

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I really appreciate it. I couldn´t find a way.

Comment: You're welcome! but next time please, try to write down all the details we need in order to answer your question! :D As you can see, it generated quite a lot of confusion since no one knew what you were looking for, eheh :)

Comment: Yes! I apologize for the confusion :) Thanks again for your time :D

Answer (score 2):

One of my math mantras is
"always expand around zero".

In this case,
that means 
we want to show that
$\lim_{x \to 0} e^{x+a}
= e^a
$.

But
$e^{x+a}-e^a
=e^a(e^x-1)
=e^a(e^x-e^0)
$.

Suppose we can show that
$e^x$
is continuous at $0$.
This means that,
for any $\delta > 0$
we can find an
$\epsilon(\delta) > 0$
such that
$|x| < \epsilon(\delta)$
implies that
$|e^x-1| < \delta$.
I'll leave this as an exercise.

To then show that
$e^x$ is continuous at $a$,
we need to show that,
for any $\delta > 0$
we can find an
$\epsilon > 0$
such that
$|x| < \epsilon$
implies that
$|e^{x+a}-e^a| < \delta$.
But this is the same as
$|e^{x}-1| < \delta e^{-a}$.

Under the assumption
that $e^x$
is continuous at zero,
consider
$\epsilon(\delta e^{-a})$.
By the definition of
$\epsilon(\delta)$,
if $|x| < \epsilon(\delta e^{-a})$
then
$|e^x-1|
< \delta e^{-a}
$,
which is the same as
$|e^{x+a}-e^x|
< \delta
$.

Therefore,
$e^x$ continuous at zero
implies that
$e^x$ is continuous everywhere.

A hint for showing
$e^x$ is continuous at zero:
$e^x-1
=\int_0^x e^t\, dt
$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @marycohen. I really appreciate your time :)   It is very clear