# Using the precise definition of a limit to show that the limit of $\exp(x)$ as $x$ goes to $0$ is $1$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, exponential-function

Use the precise definition of a limit to show that
$$\lim_{x\to 0} e^x=1.$$

By definition, I understand I need to show that:

for every $\epsilon>0$, there exists a $\delta>0$ such that $0<|x-0|<\delta \implies |e^x-1|<\epsilon$ for all $x$.

I am able to show this, by finding such $\delta$, if I assume $(e^x-1)>0$ but otherwise not.

Any idea on how to proceed with the general case with the absolute value is appreciated.

Comment: What is your definition of $e^x$?

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for mathematical formulas in your MSE questions.

Comment: Hi Kay. Are you willing to type your demonstration for the $e^x-1>0$ case, above?

Comment: Anyway, this has been asked before. See [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2993570), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1008427), [3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2490062), [4](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/776375), [5](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1008427)

Comment: Found using [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Clim_%7Bx%5Cto0%7De%5Ex%3D1%24&p=1)